# Search for issues in Jira

Tags: jira

I am new to Jira so the question is as follows. How in Jira to find all issues by a certain label and containing a certain text (in the title or description of the issue) ?

Answer (score 1):

Working out the answer to this question could be done easily by reading some related SO questions, and the official documentation and learning from them. Please try to do your own research first before posting on SO.

That being said, here's the (an) answer:

The JQL search query would be something like `(summary ~ "text" OR description ~ "text") AND labels in ("label1", "label2")`

I strongly suggest reading the [Jira documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwareserver/searching-for-issues-939938681.html) if you expect to do this often, to get a proper understanding. Also make sure to change to cloud docs if you arent on server or DC (however its not very different so not a big deal).

Answer (score 0):

There is one search box at the top right corner where you can search the JIRA item by id or description